# Tone.js User set parameters

Tags: reactjs, tone.js

I am trying to have users eventually select the note they would like to use, but first to test this feature out I mapped out a few buttons that should play the desired note when clicked.

The following snippet is how Tone.js normally works.
`synth.triggerAttackRelease("C5", "8n")`

The following snippet expresses how I would like it to work.
`synth.triggerAttackRelease(btnId, "8n")`

I get the following error even though btnId is returning as a corresponding note, for example "A4".
`Uncaught Error: Invalid argument(s) to setValueAtTime: "A", 0.1`
**A is a note in this case.**

Here is a full block of code for example of a working function

```
   import * as Tone from 'tone'
   import {Notes} from './Notes.js';
   const synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();
   
   export default Class SynthDisplay extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.btnClick = this.BtnClick.bind(this);
      }
      btnClick () {
         synth.triggerAttackRelease("C5", "8n");
      }
      render(){
         return(
           <button onClick={btnClick} />
          )
      }
   }
```

Here is the code I would like to work

```
import React from 'react';


export default class SpinDial extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {Notes: props.Notes, Tone: props.Tone, array: []};
        this.renderNotes = this.renderNotes.bind(this);
        this.btnPress = this.btnPress.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.renderNotes();
    }
    renderNotes () {
        const notes = this.state.Notes;
        const array = this.state.array;
        for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i ++) {
            array.push(<button className="noteBtn" key={notes[i] + i} id={notes[i]} onClick={this.btnPress}>{notes[i]}</button>);
        }
        const mapArray = array.map((object, index) => {
            return <div className={"mapDiv"} key={index} value={object.id}>{[object]}</div>
        });
        this.setState({
            array: mapArray
        });
    }
    btnPress (e) {
        const btnId = e.target.id;
        const noteBtnArray = document.getElementsByClassName("noteBtn");
        for (let i = 0; i < noteBtnArray.length; i++) {
            if (noteBtnArray[i].id === btnId) {
                console.log("Match" + noteBtnArray[i] + " " + btnId);
                const synth = new this.state.Tone.Synth().toDestination();
                synth.triggerAttackRelease(btnId, "8n");

            } else {
                console.log("Fail" + noteBtnArray[i] + " " + btnId);
            }
        }

    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>{this.state.array}</div>
            
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: hello can you show us some code it would be esier to help you, thanks

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. I edited my original post with some better examples. Feel free to let me know if you need more information, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I realized that some of the notes I had such as D# and E# in my Notes.js file is not how they are actually listed in the documentation. The above code should work as long as the notes are matching the documentation.